My file json doesn't work correctly. this is my code below
first file
lista_users = []
print('lets create your data, and then store into a file json')
while True:

    store_data = {
        'name': '',
        'gmail':'',
        'dni': '',
    }
    lista_users.append(store_data)
    name = input('name:')
    store_data['name'] = name
    if name == 'q':
        break
    gmail = input('gmail:')
    store_data['gmail'] = gmail
    dni= input('dni:')
    store_data['dni'] = dni

2 file
from store_user_dictionaries import lista_users as usersData
from pathlib import Path
import json

def store_data():
    for k in usersData:
        path = Path('data_users.json')
        content = json.dumps(k,indent=4)
        path.write_text(content)

def show_the_data():

    path = Path('data_users.json')
    content = path.read_text()
    loads = json.loads(content)
    for k,v in loads.items():
        print(f"These are the results of your data:\n {k}")

store_data()
show_the_data()

3#the results of my file json.
{
    "name": "q",
    "gmail": "",
    "dni": ""
}

I do not understand why the data of my users_list is not imported correctly, the final result is not as expected, I do not understand it, in my final result I should see 3 different users with their respective data.

Please update your question with a sample session you have with your program. If you enter q straight away, this is the result I would expect.

maybe dont append it to the list before its contents are ready to be appended

write_text opens, writes, and closes the file in one operation; overwriting an existing file if present, so writing each element separately ends up with a file with only the last element.
Write the entire list at once instead of each element:
def store_data():
    path = Path('data_users.json')
    content = json.dumps(usersData, indent=4)
    path.write_text(content)

Additionally, don’t append to your list if name is 'q':
lista_users = []
print('lets create your data, and then store into a file json')
while True:
    store_data = {}  # initialization not needed
    name = input('name:')
    if name == 'q':
        break
    store_data['name'] = name
    gmail = input('gmail:')
    store_data['gmail'] = gmail
    dni= input('dni:')
    store_data['dni'] = dni
    lista_users.append(store_data). # moved

